SQL Anywhere 17 Silent Installation
My requirement is, Administration Tools (32-bit) and SQL Anywhere 32-bit (Server as well as client enabled)
I have passed the silent installation command in my Dockerfile
setup.exe /s ....... So on Regkey etc and SA32=1 AT32=1
It gets installed successfully, but server 32-bit is not enabled because when I verified dbeng dbserv all these files are missing in Bin32 folder
There are no additional commands to enable the SQL Anywhere 32-bit (server) feature, and client is by default enabled.
What do I do? Please share your knowledge!

Why do you need 32bit version specifically? If setup.exe sees that the machine (docker in your case) is a 64-bit, it will install the 64-bit engine.
And if you have a 64 bit server, you can safely and reliably connect to it from 32-bit client. SQL Anywhere is very flexible.
If you really need a 32-bit server inside your docker container - just copy the executable and its dlls from your machine where you have them. There is no need to do a special setup for SA.
